# How to run activity, if app in background?

Tags: java, android

I writing the network application and i have a problem with starting activity if the application in background. I want to start activity when some data comes to network. In my Actity A a have a receiver and when it receive some answer from server, it must run the Activity B. But if the App in background, Activity B not starting and metod onCreate() doesn`t execute. It execute only when the user go back to App. But its not really what i want, becouse in Activity B i need to start timer and i neen to enable GPS and some other work. Besides that, Activity B receive some data too, and if B not existing - this receiver will never receive anything.
I tryed IntentServise, but its not working - result the same as without him.
Any ideas? Thanks for any information :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your receiver is not getting intents when your app is background, for example if you're unregistering it in onDestroy method...
try declaring your broadcast receiver in manifest. In broadcast receiver class use starActivity to call act B. This works for me.

If you still have some problems maybe you should provide some source code(for example function where you're working with intents) to clarify your question.

Comment: Its not BroadcastReciever - its just a Singletone Object with interface which Activity implements. And i totally know, that its work and its code a execute. Receiver work, and it create Intent and run startActivity(), but this activity REALY starts ONLY when user go back from app.

Comment: As i posted @If you still have some problems maybe you should provide some source code(for example function where you're working with intents) to clarify your question.@

Answer (score 0):

You can't force activity to come back from background. You can use status bar to show notification for a user. Think also about it that this a mobile device, someone can in the middle of conversation or use GPS as navigation in car.

Comment: If a can`t do this, how i can avoid this situation? Probably, the disable HOME button makes help? Because i dont want to detect if the app in background or not and starts or not starts the servise witch starting needed me timer and after Activity B is start, connecting to this servise and other difficult and hard work...(

Comment: Unfortunately you can't override HOME button.

Comment: As far as i know, the HOME button disables with follow code: @Override
 public void onAttachedToWindow()
 {this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
  super.onAttachedToWindow();
 }